# Python increment not working in while loop

Tags: while-loop, increment, python-3.9

I am trying to increase the value of the variable called "round" by 1 each time it loops, but the variable always show 2 and continues to show 2 each time the loop runs.

```
round = 1
if quitGame == "N":
         break
    else:
        round += 1
        print(f"Round({round})")
```

I don't know what to do at this point.

Here is the full code...

```
from random import random, randint
import random

running = True
global p_wins,p_losses,p_draws,c_wins,c_losses,c_draws
p_wins = 0
p_losses = 0
p_draws = 0
c_wins = 0
c_losses = 0
c_draws = 0

print("=====Rock Paper Scissors: The Python Game=====")
print("\n")
name = input("Player please enter you name:\n")
print("\n")
print("\n")

while running == True:
    
#Point System
    def Score():

        print("====Player's Score====")
        print(f"Wins:{p_wins}")
        print(f"Losses:{p_losses}")
        print(f"Draws:{p_draws}")

        print("====CPU's Score====")
        print(f"Wins:{c_wins}")
        print(f"Losses:{c_losses}")
        print(f"Draws:{c_draws}")

    if len(name) > 12:
        print("Player's name is TOO long")
        break

    myItem = input("Enter Either Rock Paper or Scissors:\n")
    print("\n")
    print(f"{name} chooses {myItem}...")


    if myItem not in ("Rock","Paper","Scissors"):
       print("Are you Ok!! I said enter rock paper or scissors")
       print("GAME OVER!!!!!!")
       break
    

#Computer's Choices
    computerItem = random.randint(1,3)
    if computerItem == 1:
        computerItem = "Rock"
        print(f"Computer chooses {computerItem}...")
    if computerItem == 2:
        computerItem = "Paper"
        print(f"Computer chooses {computerItem}...")
    if computerItem == 3:
        computerItem = "Scissors"
        print(f"Computer chooses {computerItem}...")


    if myItem == computerItem:
        print("Try Again!! You and the CPU picked the same thing")
        p_draws += 1
        c_draws += 1
        Score()
        

#Game Rules
    if myItem == "Rock" and computerItem == "Paper":
        print("[Paper covers Rock]")
        print("CPU WINS!!!")
        p_losses += 1
        c_wins += 1
        Score()
        
    if myItem == "Paper" and computerItem == "Rock":
        print("[Paper covers Rock]")
        print(f"{name} WINS!!!")
        p_wins += 1
        c_losses += 1
        Score()

    if myItem == "Scissors" and computerItem == "Rock":
        print("[Rock Smashes Scissors]")
        print("CPU WINS!!!")
        p_losses += 1
        c_wins += 1
        Score()
        
    if myItem == "Rock" and computerItem == "Scissors":
        print("[Rock smashes Scissors]")
        print(f"{name} WINS!!!")
        p_wins += 1
        c_losses += 1
        Score()
        

    if myItem == "Paper" and computerItem == "Scissors":
        print("[Scissors cut Paper]")
        print("CPU WINS!!!")
        p_losses += 1
        c_wins += 1
        Score()
        

    if myItem == "Scissors" and computerItem == "Paper":
        print("[Scissors cut Paper]")
        print(f"{name} WINS!!!")
        p_wins += 1
        c_losses += 1
        Score()
        
    round = 1
    quitGame = input("Do you want to continue playing (Y/N):\n")

    if quitGame == "N":
         break
    else:
        round += 1
        print(f"Round({round})")
```

For context, I am making a rock, paper, scissors game using python. I want to print the print "Round(num)" every time a new round has begun but it just isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the variable inside the loop. So at each iteration the value is set to 1 again and increment 1, forever.

Like this:

```
for i in [1,2]:
   a = 1
   a +=1
   print (a) # 2
```

But that is different of:

```
a = 1    
for i in [1,2]:
   a +=1
   print (a) # 2
```